# File Explorer for Android 8 is crashing even after permission given

Tags: android, file, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm trying to get this https://bluexmas.tistory.com/427?category=556203 file explorer to work in Android 8. It keeps crashing  even if I give runtime permissions, although it works in my Android 4.2.2.

I tried to rebuild the jar file from android-file-dialog again
using `jar cf lib_fileexplorer.jar FileDialog.java` and replaced the original one, but still the same issue. 
I've followed this thread to give runtime permissions, http://blog.blong.com/2018/11/rad-studio-103-rio-supports-android.html

I'm not sure what is the problem in android 8 that keep the app crashing.
need some insight, please.

Crash Log using ADB logcat AndroidRuntime:E *:S

```
08-03 16:19:18.998  5982  5982 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-03 16:19:18.998  5982  5982 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.embarcadero.FileExplorer, PID: 5982
08-03 16:19:18.998  5982  5982 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.embarcadero.FileExplorer/com.lamerman.FileDialog}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
```

monitor.bat log :

```
08-03 20:07:37.238: E/AndroidRuntime(17337): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-03 20:07:37.238: E/AndroidRuntime(17337): Process: com.embarcadero.FileExplorer, PID: 17337
08-03 20:07:37.238: E/AndroidRuntime(17337): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.embarcadero.FileExplorer/com.lamerman.FileDialog}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
08-03 20:07:37.238: E/AndroidRuntime(17337):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2904)
08-03 20:07:37.238: E/AndroidRuntime(17337):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2979)
08-03 20:07:37.238: E/AndroidRuntime(17337):    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
08-03 20:07:37.238: E/AndroidRuntime(17337):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1643)
08-03 20:07:37.238: E/AndroidRuntime(17337):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
08-03 20:07:37.238: E/AndroidRuntime(17337):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:180)
08-03 20:07:37.238: E/AndroidRuntime(17337):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
08-03 20:07:37.238: E/AndroidRuntime(17337):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-03 20:07:37.238: E/AndroidRuntime(17337):    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
08-03 20:07:37.238: E/AndroidRuntime(17337):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:853)
08-03 20:07:37.238: E/AndroidRuntime(17337): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
08-03 20:07:37.238: E/AndroidRuntime(17337):    at com.lamerman.FileDialog.getDirImpl(FileDialog.java:250)
08-03 20:07:37.238: E/AndroidRuntime(17337):    at com.lamerman.FileDialog.getDir(FileDialog.java:202)
08-03 20:07:37.238: E/AndroidRuntime(17337):    at com.lamerman.FileDialog.onCreate(FileDialog.java:193)
08-03 20:07:37.238: E/AndroidRuntime(17337):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6986)
08-03 20:07:37.238: E/AndroidRuntime(17337):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1232)
08-03 20:07:37.238: E/AndroidRuntime(17337):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2857)
08-03 20:07:37.238: E/AndroidRuntime(17337):    ... 9 more
```

Comment: provide crash logs

Comment: added @OmInfowaveDevelopers

Comment: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException check which resource missing on the screen where the crash happening

Comment: there are only 7 resources and i'm pretty sure everything is correct in deployment, i 've added the monitor.bat log,@MikeM.

Comment: in the permission tab in the setting, Storage is granted permission. i'm not passing anything, just starting the activity `com.lamerman.FileDialog` @MikeM.

Comment: strange, ok.. `https://www69.zippyshare.com/v/JRuQn8WB/file.html` @MikeM.